# Setting joint velocity from a plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to simulating an obstacle avoiding robot in gazebo. I've been following [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base_laser) tutorial.

The problem is that this tutorial uses in order to move the robot.

> SetForce(0, torque);

The problem with that is it eventually makes robot to spin.

So i looked in API ref and found

> SetVelocity(0, vel);

Code compiles just fine however, this doesn't seem to have any effect on model.
So how can I set velocity of wheels from a plugin ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5226/setting-joint-velocity-from-a-plugin/) by [SpiderRico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/605/spiderrico/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You also need to call `SetMaxForce(0, max_allowed_force)`

The `max_allowed_force` is the maximum force Gazebo will apply in order to achieve the desired velocity.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/605/spiderrico/) on 2014-01-17**:
Ty mate ! However, I still wonder about why SetVelocity is not working though.